# server not returning xhr.responseText proparly outside the server

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I am throwing an error from function which is exists in controller please see my below code

```
[HttpPost]
    [CustomJsonExceptionHandler]
    public ActionResult GetList(int month, int year)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Exception");
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> List = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>()
        return Json(List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


public class CustomJsonExceptionHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
{

    IAbsenceLogService _absenceLogRepository;

    public CustomJsonExceptionHandler()
    {
        if (_absenceLogRepository == null)
            _absenceLogRepository = new AbsenceLogRepository();
    }

    //Custom Json exception Handler
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            IConfigurationSource configurationSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
            if (configurationSource.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configurationSource);
                    Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriterFactory.Create());
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    string msg = exc.Message;
                }
            }
            Exception exception = new Exception();
            ExceptionPolicyFactory exceptionFactory = new ExceptionPolicyFactory(configurationSource);
            ExceptionManager exceptionManager = exceptionFactory.CreateManager();
            exceptionManager.HandleException(filterContext.Exception, "ExceptionPolicy", out exception);


            try
            {
                //Save exception in database
                _absenceLogRepository.WriteExceptionLog(filterContext.Exception, filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptionManager.HandleException(ex, "ExceptionPolicy", out exception);
            }

            //returning json result
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    errorMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message
                }
            };
        }
    }

}
```

I have imported following js files in my html code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

Please see my below code in jquery

`$.fn.GetData = function (month, year) {
        var data = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/HomeCalendar/GetList',
            data: { month: month, year: year },
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function (Listdata) {
                data = Listdata;
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                var jsonerror = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
                alert(jsonerror.errorMessage)
            }
        });
        return data;
    }`

I am getting JsonResult in error

Here, another issue is, server not returning xhr.responseText proparly outside the server. Working fine in same server.

Please help

Comment: It's not clear where this exception is thrown and how your code is being used. You can try attaching the Visual Studio JScript debugger to the process where the error occurs and enable breaking on JScript exceptions to see where exactly the exception is thrown and what is the context (such as what is the ominous object which is null or undefined).

Comment: This exception is thrown in jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: Yes but this doesn't explain the context. Especially the call stack and the local variables (in particular the object the code tries to access) would be interesting. And something must have called into jQuery in the first place I'd guess.

Comment: Yor are correct Cherry. Please see my below code in jqury

Comment: About your code: I still don't get the full picture but what I can puzzle together is that your server is not responding correctly (probably with an error status), and `xhr.responseText` is not set. However you don't check this and just feed it into `$.parseJSON` and this is why it fails (internally, jQuery will ultimately try to get the length of the string you passed, which fails because it's not a string but nothing at all, and that's where the error comes from). To further investigate your problem, you should use the "network" tab (or similar) of your browser's devtools to inspect the data

Comment: I assume you are using IE (according to your error message). You should be able to press F12 in the browser to open the devtools. There, you can open the "Network" tab to see all network requests sent by the page. While this tab is open, refresh the page so that the problematic request is sent again. You will then see the request details in the network tab and you will be able to click on it to see exactly what the browser sent to and received from your server. Maybe this will reveal the actual root cause of your problem.